# JavaFx. Is there a way to programmatically scroll GridView?

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, controlsfx

I need to use `GridView` in my project. And I want to scroll programmatically to the view in this `GridView`. Is there a way to do this? From what I know you can only programmatically scroll a `ScrollPane`.

Answer (score 1):

Just put your GridView into a ScrollPane. Then you can scroll the ScrollPane.